# Add custom text on Contact Form 7 Wordpress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I've styled and prepared my Contact Form on my website (using Wordpress plugin called Contact Form 7).

I've styled the form, and made everything as I want it. But I only have one problem. I can't figure out how to enter custom text in a specific part of my contact form.

This is the page: http://digesale.com/contact-us/

You will obviously see an empty part in the upper right corner of the form. I want to write some text there. I tried googling for a solution, and I tried looking through the plugin's settings and even php files. I can't figure it out.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: for confirmation please check screenshot http://awesomescreenshot.com/0a761bcg19

Comment: want to show something like this http://awesomescreenshot.com/01c61bd702         ?

Comment: Hey Raj, yes that is Exactly what I want :) Sorry for the delay to reply. I just woke up. Can you help me, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Nice you achieved it good to see

Answer (score 0):

You can add the code where you are adding the fields in contact form 7. You can do customize there by your own html.

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys. So I managed to do it. I went into Contact Form's settings. And I added the following:

`<div style="float:right; width: 365px; margin-top: -160px; font-weight:bold; margin-right:10px; font-style:italic; font-size:13px;">`MY TEXT AND LINKS AND EVERYTHING`</div>`

You can see how it looks if you check the page using the link in my original post.

Now, if anyone sees a mistake or something I could do better, do tell? I used CSS to position and style the text and everything. I hope I did it well to work on mobile and all devices and everything. I'm an amateur with this stuff. I can get things done, but don't even start with cross-device compatibility and stuff like that. :)